# How can I display something from another page by using HTML/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have looked around for answers to this question but either do not understand the logic of the other answer, or have done something wrong trying to incorporate those answers.

I have 2 pages of HTML, where the first page has this form

```
<form class='registerbutton' action='registration.php' method = "POST">
   <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email'>
   <input type='submit' value='Register'>
   <script> localStorage.setItem("useremail",email);</script>            
</form>
```

When I do not use the method="POST" I can see in the URL that the email value is added onto the URL and therefore that this form works. However, in my next page I have this:

```
<body>
 <script>
   var test = LocalStorage.getItem("useremail");
   document.write(test);
 </script>
</body>
```

However, this does not work. I have also tried `<?php echo email;?>` but that also does not work. I am sorry if this is a trivial question. I am more used to other programming languages and am new to web development.

Comment: 1) You haven't defined email when you try to set useremail to your localstorage.
2) var test = Localstorage should be localstorage
3) If you try to use php with this you'll have to define email. PHP file doesn't know what email is.

Comment: You need to actually submit the form or do some action before you can fetch any values. Then you would also need to populate the variable `email` from the form somehow (like a "normal" post (loads a new page) where you get the value using PHP or using JS to just get the value without leaving the current page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution will work client side only. Try it should work fine, it should work fine. If any thing else then let me know.

**Page 1**

```
<form class='registerbutton' action='registration.php' method="POST">
    <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='Email' id="emailId">
    <input type='submit' value='Register'>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var email = document.getElementById('emailId');
    email.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        localStorage.setItem('useremail', event.target.value);
    });
</script>
```

**Page 2**

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var test = localStorage.getItem("useremail");
        document.write(test);
    </script>
</body>
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
<?php
echo $_POST['email']; // In case of post and $_REQUEST['email'] will work for both.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your method is POST, so you can access your email with PHP by the following:

```
<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>
```